# Why is that checkbox not working with navigation?

Tags: html, css

I was trying to make a mobile navigation bar with Only CSS but even if checkbox works, it's not doing their job. (I changed

> `#main-navigation label { display: none;}`

to

> `display: block;`

to see if the box works.) I used

> `#toggle`

instead of

> `#main-navigation input`

but it didn't work... I used a lot things actually but there is something I made wrong or I'm missing. Please help

```css
#nav-bg {
 background-color: gray;
 width: 50%;
 height: 76px;
 right: 0;
 position: absolute;
}
#main-navigation {
 float: right;
}
#main-navigation a {
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: gray;
 color: black;
 font-size: 16px; /* (default) */
 padding: 29px;
 line-height: 76px;
 margin-left: -3px;
 border-right: solid thin;
 border-right-color: darkgray;
 transition: 800ms;
}
#main-navigation a:hover {
 background-color: black;
 color: ghostwhite;
 transition: 800ms;
 
}
.navigation-active {
 background-color: black !important;
 color: ghostwhite !important;
}
.navigation-active:hover {
 color: gray !important;
}

/* |||------------------------||| */

#main-navigation label {
 display: none;
}
#main-navigation input {
 display: block;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 950px) {
 #title-bg{
  width: 50%;
 }
 /* {sourced */
 #main-navigation label {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  font-size: 26px;
  margin: 18px 31.5px;
 }
 #main-navigation {
  display: block;
 }
 #main-navigation nav {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 76px;
  transition: 800ms;
 }
 #main-navigation a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: 14.5px;
  text-align: center;
  clear: right;
 }
 #main-navigation input:checked + #main-navigation nav {
  display: block;
 }
```

```html
<div id="nav-bg">
  <div id="main-navigation">
   <!-- sourced --->
   <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
   <label for="toggle">&#9776</label>
   <!-- /sourced -->
  <nav>
   <a href="#" class="navigation-active">HOME</a>
   <a href="#">QUESTS</a>
   <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
   <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
  </nav>
  </div>
  
 </div>
```

Comment: What is your goal with that checkbox? when you click, to collapse the elements??

Comment: When you change #main-navigation nav {display: none;} to display block or something, there is menu as you can see. I want to do this with checkbox. When click the box display should turn block but it doesn't work.

Comment: You can fix it by using selector `#main-navigation input:checked ~ nav` instead of `#main-navigation input:checked + #main-navigation nav`

Comment: Thanks, Vadi. It worked like a miracle. I appreciative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you just set the nav to display none and then add this input[type=checkbox]:checked~nav {
  display: block;
}

```css
#nav-bg {
 background-color: gray;
 width: 50%;
 height: 76px;
 right: 0;
 position: absolute;
}
#main-navigation {
 float: right;
}
#main-navigation a {
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: gray;
 color: black;
 font-size: 16px; /* (default) */
 padding: 29px;
 line-height: 76px;
 margin-left: -3px;
 border-right: solid thin;
 border-right-color: darkgray;
 transition: 800ms;
}
#main-navigation a:hover {
 background-color: black;
 color: ghostwhite;
 transition: 800ms;
 
}
.navigation-active {
 background-color: black !important;
 color: ghostwhite !important;
}
.navigation-active:hover {
 color: gray !important;
}

/* |||------------------------||| */

#main-navigation label {
 display: none;
}
#main-navigation input {
 display: block;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 950px) {
 #title-bg{
  width: 50%;
 }
 /* {sourced */
 #main-navigation label {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  font-size: 26px;
  margin: 18px 31.5px;
 }
 #main-navigation {
  display: block;
 }
  nav {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 76px;
  transition: 800ms;
 }
 #main-navigation a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: 14.5px;
  text-align: center;
  clear: right;
 }
 input[type=checkbox]:checked~nav {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav-bg">
  <div id="main-navigation">
   <!-- sourced --->
   <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
   <label for="toggle">&#9776</label>
   <!-- /sourced -->
  <nav>
   <a href="#" class="navigation-active">HOME</a>
   <a href="#">QUESTS</a>
   <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
   <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
  </nav>
  </div>
  
 </div>
```

Comment: It's working too, seems like another version of Vadi's method. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>



<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have to go like this. I think this one is the easiest approach.

Comment: Thanks but I think my code is more complex because of diving screen two side. And is there any way to do that without copy & paste some JS code? With CSS I mean

Comment: check this https://medialoot.com/blog/how-to-create-a-responsive-navigation-menu-using-only-css/

Comment: Thank you. That was helpful for now and for the future.